# asp-route-id determine value dynamically with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax

*Hello I need to pass value from "codeDrink" to my controller via "asp-route-id" dynamically using "ajax". I am using asp.net mvc*

**my view**

```
   <p>
        <a id="deleteLink" asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="User" asp-route-id="">
            <input id="btnSetPay" class="button" type="button" value="Оплатить"></a>
   </p>



<script>
        var deleteLink = document.getElementById('deleteLink');

        var id = document.getElementById("codeDrink").value;
        // or var id = 100;

        function getId() {
            fetch('/User/GetId/' + id, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    id = data.id;

                    deleteLink.setAttribute('asp-route-id', id);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                });
        }
        getId();
    </script>
```

**my controller**

```
    public int GetId(int id)
    {
        return _context.Drinks.Single(x => x.Id == id).Id;
    }
```

Comment: `asp-route-id` is a *server-side* attribute.  The HTML/JavaScript has no knowledge of this attribute, and setting it client-side will do nothing.  In your browser's debugging tools, examine the actual `<a>` element that's on the page.  What is that element?  What information within that element do you want to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by getting rid of the "asp-route-id" and rewriting the "ajax" request

```
 <p>
    <label for="codeDrink">Код напитка:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="number" id="codeDrink" name="codeDrink" min=@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First().Id)
           max=@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Last().Id)>
    <br><br>
    <label for="valueCoin">Сумма:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="number" id="valueCoin" name="valueCoin">&nbsp;
    <input id="btnCoin1" onclick="SetCoin(id)" class="submit submit3" type="submit" value=1>
    <input id="btnCoin2" onclick="SetCoin(id)" class="submit submit3" type="submit" value=2>
    <input id="btnCoin5" onclick="SetCoin(id)" class="submit submit3" type="submit" value=5>
    <input id="btnCoin10" onclick="SetCoin(id)" class="submit submit3" type="submit" value=10>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSetPay" class="submit">Оплатить</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btnGetPay" class="submit submit2">Получить сдачу</button>
</p>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSetPay').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Отменить стандартное действие отправки формы
            var codeDrink = $('#codeDrink').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', // Используйте 'POST', если ваше действие требует метода POST
                url: '/User/Delete', // Замените на фактический URL вашего действия контроллера
                data: { codeDrink: codeDrink },
                success: function (result) {
                    // Обработка успешного ответа от сервера
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    // Обработка ошибки
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).